# VSO Package Library - Nuget Delayed

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Our team has a private Package Feed set up in Visual Studio Online. We can push the latest version of a library we are working on to the feed, and then see it in our NuGet package manager in VS2017.

In the last few weeks, this process has become unreliable, and we cannot determine why.

Steps:

1. A developer builds nuget a package locally.
2. We push the package to our feed using the command line

   1. `nuget.exe push -Source "VSO-Feed" -ApiKey VSTS ..\Project\bin\Debug\Project.0.1.1-alpha.nupkg`
   2. Command returns success
3. We can see new new package version under "Packages" in VSO
4. NuGet Package Manager in VS 2017 cannot find the new package
5. Attempts to update the `.csproj` file manually to reference the new version sometimes succeed, but just as frequently the project build fails with a message like

> Unable to find package Project with version (>= 0.1.1-alpha)
>
> Found 243 version(s) in vso-feed [ Nearest version: 0.1.0-alpha ]

6. After an indeterminate period of time, usually at least 45 minutes, it suddenly works again!

Has anyone else experienced this? Our searches have come up empty.

Comment: First, make sure that "Include prerelease" option is checked when you have pre-release packages in your package feed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249038/cannot-find-package-from-nuget-stream-hosted-in-artifactory/46399475#46399475. If you have already do it, it seems you are in a lower network speed environment or you have many packages in the feed, you can try to create a new feed with the latest version 0.1.1-alpha, check if it still have this issue.

Comment: Again, after push the latest nuget package to the feed, have you try to list this packages with the nuget cli: `nuget list -Source xxx -PreRelease`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-list

Comment: Yes, we have "include prerelease" checked, and we can list all the packages as well. You mentioned having a large number of packages - we do have many package versions. Can that cause a problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on another machine? What's the result if you try with a new package (not existing in VSTS)

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce it. About half our team is seeing this problem.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Seeing exactly the same issues here. Even a build running on VSO itself cannot retrieve the nuget package that shows in the VSO UI.

Comment: You may post the issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Comment: @IanMercer how many versions do you have in your repository - we found it got much better after we deleted all the old versions we weren't using anymore.